# Setup SPA Frontend and Backend as separate Azure AD App Registrations

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal, azure-authentication

I have a SPA (Angular) frontend that communicates with a .NET Core backend, where the backend application is configured to have multiple authentication schemes to not only allow for the SPA frontend to authenticate users registered under the current tenant, but also other APIs (which are registered in Azure AD as separate application registrations).

For each environment, I've registered the frontend and the backend as 2 separate applications, and setup the various scopes, exposed APIs, permissions etc to facilitate the necessary communication using the newer MSAL auth code flow (external APIs that communicate with the backend for each environment use a different authentication flow).

Is it advised to have this configuration, or should I instead treat my frontend and backend as a single application registration?

On one hand, I feel that my frontend is simply another application that is communicating with my backend. But on the other, it could be considered part of the same fundamental 'application'.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2 app registrations is what is normally advised - it helps on a better separation of concepts, making things clearer.

You can also see this on the official MS Samples, where they always provide the steps to register both client and service apps. Check the following example for an Angular SPA and .NET Core API:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api

Comment: That was exactly what I was thinking - do you think there's any benefit to having a single app registration instead?

Comment: I have been working with AAD and MSAL for some years now and honestly there is no benefit that I can think of.

Comment: The only situation where I only used one app registration was when adding authentication to Swagger. Despite being a "frontend", it is just a frontend page of the API, it ends up being on the same domain, so on this type of cases I use the API app reg as the Swagger client as well

Comment: I did the same thing with Hangfire and Swagger setting up authentication as part of the API - also didn't see the benefit in separating it out since that would also need to be done for other environments. Thanks for the feedback! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it **depends** on the **architecture** of your software.

If you have a **multiservice architecture** in which each service **communicates directly** with the **app** and is integrated, you should always have one **app registration per service** and a separate one for your app.

However, the whole thing becomes problematic if, for example, you operate **role management** and want to **secure** your **API routes** based on these roles.

In these cases, it makes sense to **create a backend for frontend** and control the **services** in the background via **client credential flow** using the app-specific API.

I would always authorize the **backend for frontend** with the **same** **AppRegistration as** the one for the **app**.
This makes **role management easier**.

In our use cases, we even have rest services in the background that we link to a BFF and then continue to work with the frontend via GraphQL and **websockets for live updates**.
For live updates **between** the **services**, we use the **event-driven** pattern with EventHub, ServiceBus or, in some cases, Kafka.
But none of this is a problem because we use **[MassTransit](https://masstransit.io/)** as the interface framework.

I myself am a software architect and have more than 10 years of professional experience in web development.

But at the end of the day, it should definitely be a standardized solution for all your web applications.